# Can I hang a picture frame on drywall?

Tags: drywall, drill

I have a drywall (I think - could be gypsum, but I do not think it matters), where I want to hang a frame (quite light initially, think poster with plastic frame).

I can see behind my drywall, and I have two options:

- hollow plug in the drywall, which is about 9mm (0.35 inches) thick
- there is a drywall beam (yes, the beam is made of drywall as far as I can tell. For the context, this is around an out of use chimney, that's why I think is drywall all the way and no wood), horizontal, in a position practical enough for me to drill in. This would give me depth of 32mm (1.26 inches).

Would it be preferable to go the usual hollow plug way, or would it be better to take advantage of the beam (and then I am not sure which kind a plug to use)?

Comment: For something that lite, almost any drywall anchor will do.  Heavier stuff should be screwed into studs.  I have never heard of a drywall beam, concrete or maybe it is a wood stud covered with something(drywall dust).

Comment: A picture of this "drywall beam" would be most helpful, as that's an _extremely_ unusual construction...

Comment: Maybe the "drywall beam" is simply blocking (maybe fireblocking, or a vestige of a cabinet)?

Answer (score 5):

A "quite light" picture frame can certainly be hung using hollow-wall anchors. The confusion about your situation aside, it's not a concern. The package on most such anchors will list a capacity of at least say 15 lbs. *per device*, and your frame sounds like it's less that that. Multiple anchors, properly implemented, will far exceed your needs.

Comment: (assuming the drywall beam thing is correct - I do not have a pic yet to confirm) if I need to drill into 32mm of drywall, any hollow plug is too small. Is there a best way to do this?

Comment: If that's two layers of drywall panels, shorter anchors will still work fine. You just need to get past the second paper face. There's no such thing as a "drywall beam", though. Gypsum isn't structural except as a wall sheathing.

Comment: That's the thing - I cannot find in my local DIY shop anchors going deep enough, hence my question of what could work (It probably is kinda moot as I seem to get the vibe that a drywall beam does not make sense :) )

Comment: My maint point is that you almost certainly do not have 32mm of drywall in a single panel. It's multiple layers. You don't need to get all the way through. There's still a lot of confusion about that, though. I suggest you respond to the comments on your question so we aren't throwing darts in the dark here.

Comment: @isherwood -- there are some weird old wall constructions that used gypsum ribs inside the wall

Answer (score 4):

For something as light as a picture frame, I'd just bang a panel pin in at 45°.

I've a houseful of pictures on the walls, some as wood-framed canvases as big as 120 x 80cm - which get 2 nails, mainly for stability rather than strength.

For a large frame with glass, I might go for something more substantial - but these are still just 'posh' panel pins [some at at 45°], just with more pins.

[image] [image] [image]
<sub>Click for full size</sub>